# Dynamically created sections with unique backgrounds

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, background-image

I am creating a Wordpress theme that displays all the pages as sections on one single page and the menu scrolls to each section. I want the user to be able to set a unique background for each page (this will be the featured image of a page). What I've found though is that when a user sets the image for one page, it becomes the background image for ALL pages.

How can I adapt my code so that the user can set a unique background image for each page? Below is my code to create all pages and display them on one page:

```
<?php $pages = get_pages(array('sort_column' => 'menu_order'));
foreach ($pages as $page_data) {
    $content = apply_filters('the_content', $page_data->post_content);
    $title = $page_data->post_title;
        $slug = $page_data->post_name;
    //get url of featured image
    $thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
    $thumb_url_array = wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumb_id, 'thumbnail-size', true);
    $thumb_url = $thumb_url_array[0];
    //check if page has featured image
    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
    $featured_image = $thumb_url;
    }
    else {
$featured_image = '';
    }
    echo "<section id='$slug'  class='main fullscreen'>";
echo '<article class="main parallax" style="background:url(' . $featured_image . ') 50% 0 repeat fixed;">';
echo $content;
    echo '</article>';
echo "</section>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that the

```
$thumb_url_array = wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumb_id, 'thumbnail-size', true);
```

line is adding the value to the next position in the array rather than replacing the [0] position?  Perhaps changing that line to

```
$thumb_url_array[0] = wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumb_id, 'thumbnail-size', true);
```

would result in the correct value being assigned to $thumb_url and later $featured_image in the if statement.

Comment: I'm afraid this solution didn't work. It just removed the featured image from all sections

Comment: Bummer... worth a shot I guess.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change

```
$thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
```

to

```
$thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id($pages_data->ID);
```

Comment: You also need to pass the page ID to `has_post_thumbnail()`